# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context in `ForEach` over array of custom class

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I know there's a lot of questions asking about `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context` compile-time errors, but I read a lot of them and don't seem to understand why mine's happening.

First, I have

```
protocol ExpensePeriod: AnyObject, Identifiable, Hashable {
    associatedtype Period: ExpensePeriod
    
    var type: Calendar.Component { get set }
    var interval: DateInterval { get set }
    var start: Date { get }
    var end: Date { get }
    var expenses: FetchRequest<Expense> { get }
    
    static func array(from startDate: Date, to endDate: Date) -> [Period]
    
    init(from date: Date)
}
```

ad then:

```
extension ExpensePeriod {
    
    var start: Date { interval.start }
    var end: Date { interval.end }
    var expenses: FetchRequest<Expense> {
        FetchRequest<Expense>(
            entity: Expense.entity(),
            sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "datetime", ascending: false)],
            predicate: NSPredicate(
                format: "datetime > %@ AND datetime < %@",
                argumentArray: [start, end]
            )
        )
    }
    
    static func array(of timeComponent: Calendar.Component, from startDate: Date, to endDate: Date) -> [Self] {
        var currentDate = startDate
        var array = [Self(from: currentDate)]
        while !Calendar.current.dateInterval(of: timeComponent, for: currentDate)!.contains(endDate) {
            currentDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: timeComponent, value: 1, to: currentDate)!
            array.append(Self(from: currentDate))
        }
        return array
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        lhs.interval == rhs.interval
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(interval)
    }
}
```

and then:

```
final class ExpenseYear: ExpensePeriod {
    
    typealias Period = ExpenseYear
    
    var type: Calendar.Component
    var interval: DateInterval
    
    var year: Int { Calendar.current.component(.year, from: interval.start) }
    var expenseMonths: [ExpenseMonth] {
        return ExpenseMonth.array(from: start, to: end)
    }
    
    static func array(from startDate: Date, to endDate: Date) -> [ExpenseYear] {
        array(of: .year, from: startDate, to: endDate)
    }
    
    init(from date: Date) {
        self.type = .year
        self.interval = Calendar.current.dateInterval(of: type, for: date)!
    }
}
```

now the main SwiftUI view:

```
struct ListView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var managedObjectContext
    @FetchRequest(
        entity: Expense.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "datetime", ascending: false)]
    ) var expenses: FetchedResults<Expense>
    
    @State private var showingNewExpenseSheet = false
    @State private var showingPreferencesSheet = false
    
    private var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "YYYY MMM"
        return formatter
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(ExpenseYear.array(from: expenses.last!, to: expenses.first!)) { expenseYear in
                    ForEach(expenseYear.expenseMonths) { expenseMonth in
                        MonthlyListView(expenseMonth)
                    }
                    Text("\(0)")
                }.onDelete(perform: deleteExpenseItem)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Expenses")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
    
    func deleteExpenseItem(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        for index in offsets {
            let expense = expenses[index]
            managedObjectContext.delete(expense)
        }
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            print("Wasn't able to save after delete due to \(error)")
        }
    }
}

struct MonthlyListView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var managedObjectContext
    var expenseFetchRequest: FetchRequest<Expense>
    var expenses: FetchedResults<Expense> {
        expenseFetchRequest.wrappedValue
    }
    let expenseMonth: ExpenseMonth
    
    init(_ month: ExpenseMonth) {
        self.expenseMonth = month
        self.expenseFetchRequest = month.expenses
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Section(header: Text("\(expenseMonth.month)")) {
            ForEach(expenses) { expense in
                ExpenseRowItemView(expense)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`ExpenseRowItemView` just displays various datetime/notes items.

And Expense entity looks like:
[image]

`Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`  seems to be happening at `ForEach(ExpenseYear.array(from: expenses.last!, to: expenses.first!))` . I'm on Xcode 12 beta. Thank you for your help.

(If you are wondering why I'm going through all of this trouble just to render a list of expenses: I used to have a function that runs through every expense's `datetime` and build a nested structure of years and months for SwiftUI to render (to use Section, etc.). But I don't think this is a scalable/performant approach since this function would be called every time the view is rendered, hitting every single entry in Core Data, so I thought I'd have each monthly list handle its own FetchRequest with its own date boundaries, which would also make dynamic views such as "select a month to view a list of transactions by this month" easier. Please let me know if there's a better way as well.)

Comment: There are many absent components in provided snapshot, so it is impossible to reproduce your error. Thus to avoid guessing it would be better to see complete project code. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you didn't conform to `ExpensePeriod` in `ExpenseYear` you are missing `start` and `end` variables (most likely it's the source of error, but it's hard to tell)

After conforming, if the error persists I would replace in the loop the `MonthlyListView` view with `Text` and I would keep replacing stuff until I find the source of the error.

This error usually occurs when you are missing a keyword or formatting a loop. Most of the time it just means the compiler can't interpret what you wrote.

I would solve the issue but the code above is missing stuff to be able to run it just by copying and pasting it.

**EDIT:**

So your issue lies in the `forEach` because if you pay close attention, your code look like this `ForEach(ExpenseYear.array(from: expenses.last!, to: expenses.first!))` however, expenses is defined as follows `var expenses: FetchedResults<Expense>` where each item from this array will be of type `Expense` in your `ExpenseYear` array your header looks like this `tatic func array(from startDate: Date, to endDate: Date) -> [ExpenseYear]` which the first and 2nd parameter are of type `Date` yet you are passing them an item of type `Expense`. `expenses.last!` returns a `Expense` object and that's not a `Date`! so to solve the issue you would first have to do something like this `expenses.last!.datetime!`

So changing your code to this

`ForEach(ExpenseYear.array(from: expenses.last!.datetime!, to: expenses.first!.datetime!), id: \.id) { expense in`

should solve your problem. Keep in mind the following

1. Change this code to reflect everywhere in your app, I only changed it in 1 single instance as I have commented out the rest of your code.
2. Force unwrapping is always a bad idea, so I would suggest you handle dates correctly but guard unwrapping them first.

Also, I know you commented that I didn't need to implement `start` and `end` in `ExpenseYear` but unfortunately, I wasn't able to compile without implementing them so I had to.

Alternatively, you can change the `.array` protocol to take in an `Expense` instead of `Date` and then you handle how to return an array from the object `Expense` so your protocol would look something like this

```
static func array(from startExpense: Expense, to endExpense: Expense) -> [Period]
```

and implementation can be something like this

```
static func array(from startExpense: Expense, to endExpense: Expense) -> [ExpenseYear] {
        guard let startDate = startExpense.datetime, let endDate = endExpense.datetime else {
            return []
        }
        
        return array(of: .year, from: startDate, to: endDate)
    }
```

where you have already taken care of guarding against nil dates and you don't have to change anything except implementation (I honestly would prefer this method)

I know to implement the second method you would have to change how you set your protocol and bunch of other stuff, so what you can do is instead pass an optional `Date` to your `array`, something like this `static func array(from startExpense: Date?, to endExpense: Date?) -> [Period]`

and then guard unwrap them else return empty array. But you still have the issue of unwrapping `.last` and `.first` expense in your `ForEach` loop.

Good luck with the rest!

Comment: ExpenseYear conforms to ExpensePeriod since the extension takes care of the missing conformance you described. I actually did the replacement exercise already and narrowed it down to `ExpenseYear.array(from: expenses.last!, to: expenses.first!)`.

Comment: That's weird because on my end it says it needs to conform. Either way I agree with that Asperi commented. If you can post your question so that we can copy & paste to reproduce the bug that would make life so much easier for us to solve it.

Comment: I've pasted more code, hope it's replicable now. I'm on Xcode 12 beta.

Comment: Got it! please see my edited answer for the solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you, I'm kinda mad at myself for not noticing that I wasn't even passing in the right type of arguments...shouldn't Xcode tell me that instead of just throwing a cryptic "ambiguous" error, oh well...thank you so much again for looking into this, appreciate your effort!

Comment: I am glad I was able to help and don't worry about it. Trust me I have made plenty of silly mistakes in my career. It happens. As far as xCode, yea it should point you to where the error is really occurring but unfortunately xCode has been very buggy since the release of `swiftUI` specially in this area. Hence I started commenting out some of the code when something goes wrong. The less code the easier for xCode to really point you in the right direction. Hopefully they fix it soon.